# Does the root word mus- in Latin mean "thief"'? Mouse=thief, Moses=Extractor etc

Tags: latin, greek, hebrew, sanskrit, roots

I first got the idea of Latin `mus- = mouse = thief` from [this list](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Greek_and_Latin_roots_in_English/H%E2%80%93O)

My primary question here is whether someone can confirm this, because I have not found any direct words in Latin that indicates that `mus- = thief`. Where did the editor get this idea from?

I wondered what Tolkien and the Beowulf Poet meant by the central symbol of thief and burglar. Then I realized, if Latin `"mus-"="thief"`, which also is the root of "mouse", the Anglo-Saxon word which has cognate from ancient Sanskrit word *musha* meaning thief (and mouse).

- *Moses* is Hebraic and means "he who takes away", "The Extractor"
- *Mouse*: "takes away goods from the house", and is a kenning for thief
- *Muse* is one who extracts from the Gods
- *Moss*: life "extracted" from stone (poetically)
- *Mosquito*: little thief
- *Mist*: extracted/vaporized water
- *Mosque*: place of extraction (from matter/ego)

I realize this might sound crazy and far-fetched, but it was put together in non-scholarly haste.

Comment: Latin _mus_ doesn't mean ‘thief’ which is _fur_ in Latin. The connection of ‘mouse’ and ‘thief’ is found only in Sanskrit where both words have **roots** which are similar, but not identical: ‘mouse’ is  मूषक (mūṣaka) / मूषिक (mūṣika) with the root मूष् (mūṣ) and ‘thief’ मांषक (māṇṣaka) with the root मुष् (muṣ) as in मुष्णाति (muṣṇāti) ‘he steals’. The words of Semitic origin ‘Moses’ and ‘mosque’ are not connected with the rest. All of your question really sounds crazy, far-fetched, and very non-scholarly.

Comment: Hehe, it looks like Wiki quickly take into account our discussion in here. :-)

Comment: I'm fairly positive *muse* has nothing to do with any form of extraction, although the etymology of the word is not certain as of now. Some claim it comes from the verb *μω*, meaning *to learn about* or *research*, or from the word  *μας/μους* meaning *evolving, participating*. Another possible root is the verb *μάω-μω*, aka *to yearn for* or *to strive for*. No extraction here.
Sources (translated) [1](http://odeioopera.blogspot.com/2014/06/blog-post_6227.html), [2](https://www.greek-language.gr/digitalResources/ancient_greek/tools/liddel-scott/search.html?lq=%CE%BC%CE%AC%CF%89&exact=true)

Answer (score 8):

*Mūs* in Latin does not mean "thief", but only "mouse". (The Latin word for "thief" is *fūr*.) This word comes from an Indo-European word *mūs or *muHs, which is also the origin of the English word *mouse*.

However, there may be a connection between the Indo-European word and the notion "thief": there is a reconstructed Indo-European root *meusH- meaning "steal" (which yields the Sanskrit "thief" word you cite), and some scholars believe the "mouse" word comes from this root, so that the original meaning of "mouse" in Proto-Indo-European was "thief". This connection is uncertain, though.

The rest of the words you cite are pretty certainly unrelated. You can look up their etymologies online and see that none of them are derived from the Indo-European forms above.